# Reading file from FTP using Spring Integration facing issue in a clustered environment

Tags: spring, ftp, adapter, integration, inbound

I have an FTP Inbound Adapter which will be deployed on multiple instances of tomcat. The issue is that all instances will pull files from the remote directory but I need a single file to only be pulled once not by all instances.

Is there a way achieve this?

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried explicitly setting flag in database during process but I want something which Spring Integration provide